# Can't find Xamarin Build Host

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I installed Xamarin platform on my mac. But I can't find the Xamarin build host that and connect it to the Visual Studio on my PC. Does anyone know how to get it?

Comment: Have you configured your mac or just installed Xamarin?

Comment: just installed it, what else should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure you Mac for remote access: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/#Configuration
The new buildhost is using ssh. It is using UDP broadcasts (mDNS, a.k.a. Bonjour) for advertising itself. In some networks/routers/switches UDP broadcasts are blocked. If you still can't find it, try to use the static ip of your mac.